# J2me multithreading http data leaks from another thread

Tags: java, multithreading, http, java-me

I need to open two http connections at the same time on j2me device. So I opened two HttpConnection in two threads. But sometimes one connection received the data of the other one. How can I solve this problem?
I test the application on Nokia N70.

The code is big. I try to write some simple pseudocode.

http.java:

```
public class Http
{
    public Http()
    {
    }

    public void start(String url) {
       new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                getHttp(url);
           }
       }.start();

    }

    private void getHttp(String url) {

        InputStream is = null;
        HttpConnection http=null ;
        try {
            http= (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url);

            httpCode = http.getResponseCode();
            is = http.openInputStream();
            int ic;
            byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];

            while (!cancel && (ic = is.read(tmp, 0, 1024)) != -1) {
                line.append((char) ic);
                bao.write(tmp, 0, ic);
                 }
              //httpnotify.receive(bao.toByteArray) ;
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }

}
```

client1:

```
Http http=new Http() ;
http.setNotify(self) ;
http.start("http://....") ;
```

client2:

```
Http http2=new Http() ;
http2.setNotify(self) ;
http2.start("http://....") ;
```

Comment: Show us how you're doing it, please.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use `synchronized` keyword on the `getHttp()` method